# How to set 2 items are default selected in multiselect

Tags: jquery, multi-select, default-selected

My code below to populate multiselect with item value 1 and 2 are default selected but only item value 2 is selected :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Url_function,
        data: para_datas,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function OnPopulateControl(response) {
            list = response.d;
            control.multiselect({
                selectedList: selectedlist,
                header: false,// 0-based index
                selectedList: 2
            });
            var $select = control.multiselect('disable');
            if (list.length > 0) {
                        $select.multiselect('enable');
                        $.each(list, function () {
                            control.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                            //console.log(this['Text']);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Not available<option>');
                    }
                a_list_selected = valueselected.split(',');//valueselected = '1,2'
                for (i =0; i< a_list_selected.length; i++)
                {
                      control.val(a_list_selected[i]).attr('selected',true);

                }
                 control.multiselect('refresh'); //refresh the select here
        },
        error: function () {
            alert(Error_message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is `control.multiselect`? Or just `control` for that matter? Sounds like a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Yes, i use jquery plugin http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ . Control is $("#sid") in this case <select id='sid'></select>

Comment: what version of jquery you are using? if its 1.6 or higher you can use `.prop("selected",true)` or as @Py. said `.attr("selected","selected")`

Comment: The version of jquery is 1.4.4

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers. I resolve the problem with below code : control.find('option[value="'+a_list_selected[i]+'"]').attr('selected', true);

Answer (score 1):

From the doc of the plugin.

> Manually check or uncheck a checkbox?
>
> The checkboxes can be accessed after calling the "widget" method. Simply manually trigger the NATIVE click event on them:
>
> // manually check (or uncheck) the third checkbox in the menu:
>   $("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function(){
>      this.click();
>   });
>
> The native click event must be used (trigger('click') will not work) due to this bug in jQuery’s core.
>
> All necessary events and actions, like updating the button value, will automatically fire.
>
> Alternatively, you could give the original option tag the selected attribute, and then call MultiSelect’s refresh method.

You've opted for the selected way but in your code, your setting selected to true `control.val(a_list_selected[i]).attr('selected',true);`. The value to set it is `'selected'` like `control.val(a_list_selected[i]).attr('selected','selected');` (see http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/option/selected for example for the value it could take)

Comment: I don't understand, please explain it. :)

Comment: have you tried to put `control.val(a_list_selected[i]).attr('selected','selected');` in your code (with 'selected' instead of true)?

Comment: 'selected' or 'true' are correct, but only one item is selected, i want 2 items are selected

Comment: Are you sure that the items with the value 1 and 2 exist? (the HTML produced by you code would help)

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers. I resolve the problem with below code : control.find('option[value="'+a_list_selected[i]+'"]').attr('selected', true);

Comment: Then answer your question and accept your answer (well you might not have the right to do that before 48 hours :p)